# Proof that Littlewood-Paley vertical square function is NOT bounded on L^infinity

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The classical heat semigroup on $\mathbb{R}$  is given by 
$$
W_t f(x)=\frac{1}{t}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\pi (\frac{x-y}{t})^2}f(y)dy, \qquad t>0.
$$ 
Then the Littlewood-Paley vertical square function is defined by setting
$$
g(f)(x)=\|\partial_t W_t f(x)\|_{L^2((0,\infty),\, tdt)}, \qquad x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
It is known that $g$ is bounded on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $p\in (1,\infty)$ and of weak type (1,1), but it is $\textbf{not}$  bounded on $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

**My question is**: *what is the simplest argument showing that $g$ is not bounded on $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$*.

I would appreciate any hints!

Comment: Take $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-t^{2}}dt \in L^{\infty}$. Now its square function is $+\infty$.

Comment: Paata, thanks so much! :]